# Validate JAR as Input Stream without save a temporary file

Tags: java, validation, jar

I have a REST service write on Java that allows a user to upload a jar file. A user can upload a file using something like the following command:

```
curl --request POST --data-binary "@jarToUpload.jar" http://localhost:9090/entry-point/upload
```

the service receive the file as `InputStream`.

I need to retrive the input and check if is valid JAR.

If jar is valid I need to store it on remote host as a stream. I don't need to save it locally.

I have find the way to do that, but it require to create a temporary file,  validate it and than send it to remote as a stream.

```
public static File stream2file(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".jar");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return tempFile;
}


File file = stream2file(payload);
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
boolean hasManifestEntry = zip.getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") != null;

if(hasManifestEntry){
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
}
```

Is there a way to do it without save temporary file?

Comment: did you review JarInputStream?

Comment: you can keep in memory, but this is not a good idea if your app is supposed to have several simultaneous users

Comment: @AdamSkywalker can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java.util.zip.ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) class to parse Zip file on-the-fly:

```
public boolean hasManifestEntry(InputStream is) throws IOException {
  ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
  ZipEntry entry;
  while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if ("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".equals(entry.getName()))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```